# Zoomable Circle Packing with Chord D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a static JSON file that has data that is broken down in the following format. `Family of System, Location, Systems, Version`

I'm using the Zoomable Circle Packing http://bl.ocks.org/AndrewRP/7468330 which is working well. I would like to have something similar to this Chord example http://bl.ocks.org/AndrewRP/7468330 that shows the internal and external dependencies between the `Systems`.

I saw this example http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2013/02/20/movies/among-the-oscar-contenders-a-host-of-connections.html?_r=2& that would get me close however I'm not sure what this is called or another example of this that I can use as my starting point.

I'm new to D3 and a novice with JavaScript so if what I asked has been answered please point in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using a Tree instead of Circle and Chord gave me something even better. Sorry for the post